# Get the selected value of a group of HtmlInputRadioButton controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

When using the `RadioButtonList` control, I can access the selected value in my codebehind with the following:

```
rbMyButtons.SelectedValue
```

However, I'd like to use `HtmlInputRadioButton` controls instead as these give me greater control over the rendered markup. If I'm using a list of `<input type="radio" runat="server" />` then, as far as I know, I have to do something like this:

```
if (rbMyButtonsOption1.Checked)
{
    ...
}
else if (rbMyButtonsOption2.Checked)
{
    ...
}
else if ...
```

Is there a way I can mimic the behaviour of `RadioButtonList.SelectedValue` *without* using `Request.Form["name"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

First, wrap the Html Controls inside a panel or similar grouping object (the panel will be rendered as a div):

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ButtonList" ClientIDMode="Static">
   <input type="radio" name="seasons" value="Spring" runat="server" />Spring <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="seasons" value="Summer" runat="server" /> Summer <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="seasons" value="Fall" runat="server" /> Fall <br/>
   <input type="radio" name="seasons" value="Winter" runat="server" /> Winter <br/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then, create an extension method to access the ControlCollection property of the panel and iterate through the collection:

```
public static class HelperFunctions
{
    public static string GetRadioButtonValue(this ControlCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (var control in collection)
        {
            if (control is HtmlInputRadioButton)
            {
                var radioControl = ((HtmlInputRadioButton)control);
                if (radioControl.Checked)
                {
                    return radioControl.Value;
                }
            }
        }

        //If no item has been clicked or no Input Radio controls are present we return an empty string
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Finally you can get the value with ease:

```
var selectedValue = ButtonList.Controls.GetRadioButtonValue();
```

Comment: This is very much along the lines I was beginning to think. I will probably swap the panel for a placeholder but, other than that, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did some searching to find this, so thought it may be useful even though the question is over 1 year old...

I've just come across this issue. I needed to use use [input type="radio" runat="server" ...] as I had to include additional HTML "data-*" attributes against each selection.

I've used a composite of the two answers here to come with a solution that helped me.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div id="pnlOpts" runat="server">
   <input type="radio" name="rblReason" runat="server" value="1" /> <label>Opt 1</label><br />
   <input type="radio" name="rblReason" runat="server" value="3" data-att="1" /> <label>Supplied Reason 1 </label><br />
   <input type="radio" name="rblReason" runat="server" value="3" data-att="2" /> <label>Supplied Reason 2 </label><br />
   <input type="radio" name="rblReason" runat="server" value="3" data-att="3" /> <label>Supplied Reason 3 </label><br />
</div>
```

My Code-behind looks like:

```
if(pnlOpts.Controls.OfType<HtmlInputRadioButton>().Any(a=>a.Checked))
{
    HtmlInputRadioButton selected = pnlOpts.Controls.OfType<HtmlInputRadioButton>().Where(a => a.Checked).FirstOrDefault();
    var btnValue = selected.Value;
    var dataAttVal = selected.Attributes["data-att"];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic this behavior using LINQ:

```
var radioButtons = new[] { rbMyButtonsOption1, rbMyButtonsOption2 };
var checkedRadioButton = radioButtons.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Checked);
if (checkedRadioButton != null)
{
    // do something...
}
```